# MySQL grouping by day then display the date from the grouped results

Tags: php, mysql

So i have a whole load of votes going into a voting system. I want to display how many votes i have in any one day. But i also want to then, display the amount of votes per day and spit out which day they were voted on, i.e 24k votes on 05/06/12, 27k votes on 06/06/12

```
SELECT count(*) AS count
FROM results 
GROUP BY DAY(datesubmitted), YEAR(datesubmitted), MONTH(datesubmitted) 
ORDER  BY DAY(datesubmitted) DESC, YEAR(datesubmitted) DESC, MONTH(datesubmitted) DESC
```

Is my query, i tried to add something like

> DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(datesubmitted)) as order_day

but this just throws a null which i found interesting as i'd expect the query to fail as there aren't any outers.

Comment: Your initial sql query is only outputting "count". Mayhaps you have to include DAY(), YEAR() AND MONTH() to get an output.

Comment: very good indeed, cheers. Oddly i thought i had done this but sadly not... plus my ordering meant that i wasn't getting the newest results first.

Comment: added the answer, but it was you who got it :)

Comment: Cool, glad you it worked out for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So just saw a new answer but for me how i got it working was:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count, DAY(datesubmitted) AS newday, 
YEAR(datesubmitted) as newyear ,MONTH(datesubmitted) as newmonth
FROM results 
GROUP BY DAY(datesubmitted), YEAR(datesubmitted), MONTH(datesubmitted) 
ORDER  BY  YEAR(datesubmitted) DESC, MONTH(datesubmitted) DESC, DAY(datesubmitted) DESC
```

This way i get the correct ordering with year, month and day properly and also it displays the dates. I could concat them, but thats for another day.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply `GROUP BY datesubmitted DESC`? Also, no need to ORDER BY if it's following the same criteria as GROUP BY.

Comment: For `datesubmitted` column look at the comments on my answer, and you are right, MySQL does also sort when grouping - but other DB's don't (nor should they, it slows performance), so it's there purely for completeness sake.

Comment: as stated earlier the reason being i want group by the day, your way will group by each second submitted. Obviously this isn't a whole days vote. :)

Comment: Oh but you can group by DATE(datesubmitted).

Answer (score 0):

Number of votes on a specific day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM results 
WHERE datesubmitted BETWEEN @dateMin AND @dateMax
```

Number of votes for each separate day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, DATE(datesubmitted) AS day
FROM results 
GROUP BY DATE(datesubmitted)
ORDER BY DATE(datesubmitted) DESC
```

**UPDATED AGAIN**

Comment: this will group each vote as a separate results in the query. I wanted to group them together and display the total number votes from any one day. But thanks for the feedback :D

Comment: cheer fella, the first query still returns nothing  ^^ and obviously the later works :)

Comment: @JamieHutber `@dateMin AND @dateMax` are sql parameters, if you don't know how to use them, then just change it to `'05/06/12' AND '05/06/12 23:59:59'` (use server locale date formating) - it **might** return nothing if there are no records for that day, so just change it to `SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)  AS total`

Comment: @JamieHutber actually COUNT **always** returns a value (0 if no rows found), so forget about IFNULL - are you still having problems?